# After installing pyqtgraph, still getting ImportError

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I installed `pyqtgraph` in an anaconda environment by this command:

```
sudo pip install pyqtgraph
```

However, I am getting import error.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
ImportError: No module named pyqtgraph
```

I also tried  `sudo apt-get install python-pyqtgraph`, however, this also did not work. Could you please help?

Comment: are you using the correct version of pip ? try pip3 or python 3

Comment: @zython my anaconda environment is with python2.7, does this make any problem for the environment?

Comment: i just mentioned it, because I sometimes installed packages for the wrong python version and it took me forever to figure it out, I personally dont use anaconda but I'd try a combination of pip conda and python versions

Comment: I suggest too, checking different versions of python, on my mac currently I have `pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3, pip3.6` - most common reason I got an `ImportError` for me was installing the module on the wrong python version, problem gets worse with anaconda as you can have multiple versions, especially when you had installed some python versions before..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing pyqtgraph for anaconda:

```
conda install pyqtgraph
```

Comment: This probably means the pip you were using was for your system Python. The [conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages) has some instructions for how to use the correct pip if your package isn't available with conda.

Comment: @three_pineapples Thanks for your guidance.